How does 溢れる function here?
I stumbled upon this article for a while and found myself dumbfounded.
Why is に used in 若者が元気に溢れている?
Does 溢れる change its meaning depending on if the に and が is there?
It usually means ''To overflow'' but can the verb also mean ''to be overflowing with'' similarly to 満ち溢れる is translated exactly the same? Thanks in advance! :)
P.S.
If possible I would appreciate an explanation of how the に particle functions here as well.
EDIT
So I came to a conclusion but I am not sure if I am right. Feel free to reply with your own explanation of it but here is mine:
彼が喜びに溢れる
The verb is intransitive therefore the に particle is allowed. The に particle here is indirect and shows what one is overflowing with and is connected to the subject が. It is an intransitive state verb a.k.a (to be)

I'm uncertain what you're dumbfounded by.  In the linked answer, 溢れる is translated as "overflow" whether が or に is used.  I don't see a changing in meaning.  Could you clarify?

Also, in English we distinguish between "embarrassing" and "embarrassed" (はずかしい).  Japanese doesn't always draw these distinctions, you need to tease them apart.  I would say it's the same here regarding whether 溢れる is understood in English as "to overflow" or "to overflow with". I saw a comment by @naruto the other day on this topic, I don't remember which question the comment was made on.

I was going to comment about how it's just the change between subject and object, but that's explained in the other question as well

Yeah that's what I mean whether it means ''to overflow'' or ''to overflow with'' I'm kinda confused on when and how to make the distinction. When I see ''彼が喜びに溢れる'' I think ''He is overflowing in happiness'' as a mental translation but I still don't quite get it if it's right or not? I don't see where the ''with'' comes from. But maybe I'm just overthinking it

Does "I am suspicious" mean that I suspect others, or that I cause others to suspect me? Same idea.

If your understanding of "overflowing in happiness" is that the person is the "container" and the happiness is overflowing from them, then it seems fine, though it's probably not something I would say in English. There's no one-to-one correlation between prepositions and particles.

Okay last update. Deleted my last comment cause it may make more sense to me now. Since 喜び is a feeling it makes sense to use に溢れる as it is a state. ''To be overflowing of a certain emotion and considering it's intransitive the に is indirect and guides where the overflowing comes from. I might be wrong but that's what I made sense out of it.


Does 溢れる change its meaning depending on if the に and が is there?

Yes, you can understand that 溢れる has two meanings (though it is a theoretical problem how to count meanings):

Of something serving as a vessel, its content goes over from its brim
Of something being a mass, it goes over the brim of its container

But it is far from the sole example (see this question), nor is it particular to Japanese. In a bigger picture, it is one of examples that multiple framings, or perspectives, of the roughly same situation share the same verb form, which is not rare at all in English (or any language, with different examples):

"I open the door" vs. "the door opens" (ambitransitive)
"He gave me a book" vs. "He gave a book to me" (dative shift)
"I baked bread" (so that it became bread) vs. "I baked salmon" (it had been salmon, and still was salmon, more delicious though)

So in this case, you just have to look up the dictionary and memorize.

If possible I would appreciate an explanation of how the に particle functions here as well.

This is, in fact, a non-obvious question. You see the linked question says:

Just remember that when you are talking about something that is overflowing literally and not figuratively, you should put it as a subject

But this is not true. You can say something is overflowing physically with the container as subject using a different particle: for example, a hovercraft overflowing with eels is うなぎで溢れている.
The reason why you seemingly have to change the particle by figurative or not is because, に was the older version of で. で is only a post-classical particle that has displaced に for a great part of its meanings. So, in some occasions, you can replace で with に to sound loftier and more bookish. For this specific verb, however, the distinction is more or less fixed at being physical or not.

ベニスに死す (Death in Venice) ↔ ベニスで死ぬ (same but not artistic)
病に倒れる ("fall ill", "succumb to disease") ↔ 病気で倒れる (just collapsed due to illness)


I've tried to search everywhere for the meaning and why it uses the ni particle but there just isn't a good explanation about it and seems near impossible to find one.. it's either theories after theories. I give up. Feels like I'm only getting non answers.

@MathiasGlendrange this answer seems to offer a range of helpful insights and is clearly written in good faith. Is it really necessary to leave a comment under it that you consider it a "non-answer" without asking any follow-up questions on parts you feel are inadequate?
